# How to get website images src using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get all the images src/hyperlink form a webpage

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

image_list = []

r = requests.get('https://example.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

for link in soup.find_all('img'):
    image_list.append(link)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find the attributes of an html tag using `get` function. Pass the name of the attribute you want to extract from html tag to `get` function

```
for link in soup.find_all('img'):
    image_list.append(link.get('src'))
```